# I want to prevent specific value insert into ulog2_ct table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using ulog2 with mysql for gathering nf_conntrack values to DB in my bridge machine.
All things are works well, but I want to prevent to insert specific value which has "right(hex(orig_ip_saddr),8)='7f000001'".
I just execute query as "delete from ulog2_ct where right(hex(orig_ip_saddr),8)='7f000001' " periodically but its not good solution.

ulog2 provide queries to make and insert into the specific DB as https://github.com/inliniac/ulogd2/blob/master/doc/mysql-ulogd2-flat.sql
But I can't fully understand because I'm not sql expert.
I think some additional query would resolve what I want but I don't know how.

Insert query of mysql-ulogd2-flat.sql is as below: (line 435)

```
BEGIN
INSERT INTO ulog2_ct (oob_family, orig_ip_saddr, orig_ip_daddr, orig_ip_protocol,
    orig_l4_sport, orig_l4_dport, orig_bytes, orig_packets,
    reply_ip_saddr, reply_ip_daddr, reply_ip_protocol,
    reply_l4_sport, reply_l4_dport, reply_bytes, reply_packets,
    icmp_code, icmp_type, ct_mark, 
    flow_start_sec, flow_start_usec,
    flow_end_sec, flow_end_usec)
VALUES (_oob_family, _orig_ip_saddr, _orig_ip_daddr, _orig_ip_protocol,
    _orig_l4_sport, _orig_l4_dport, _orig_bytes, _orig_packets,
    _reply_ip_saddr, _reply_ip_daddr, _reply_ip_protocol,
    _reply_l4_sport, _reply_l4_dport, _reply_bytes, _reply_packets,
    _icmp_code, _icmp_type, _ct_mark,
    _flow_start_sec, _flow_start_usec,
    _flow_end_sec, _flow_end_usec);
RETURN LAST_INSERT_ID();
END
```

Seo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a trigger on ulog2_ct

(check for syntax validation , as I have just typed it here)

```
    CREATE TRIGGER trig_ulog2_ct
BEFORE INSERT ON ulog2_ct
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE msg VARCHAR(255);
    IF (right(hex(new.orig_ip_saddr),8)='7f000001') THEN
        SIGNAL 'your error message Not to insert'
    END IF;


END
```

Let us know

Comment: Oh what a good solution. I find out example of trigger and append it.
Thanks.

Comment: If it helps, can you please give a "^" to the answer as an useful answer ? It will help my ratings. Thanks :)

Comment: and also a ✓ mark is expected from you :)....It will help my score and rating. Thanks